# In angular, Subscribe function is called after all methods are called in the the component, this results that I am unable to use the response

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular-httpclient

I have tried to solve it with `await` and `async`, but as being new to typescript I am not used to these methods.
I have used `await` and `async` like this:

```
async refreshList(){
 await this.service.refreshList().subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res);
   this.service.todoListModel=res;
   });
}
```

I get to know that subscribe method parameter codes are last to execute by debugging and console output.
please help in amending my below component code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { groupBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { moveDown, slideIn, slideOut } from '../animations';
import { TodoService } from '../todo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css'],
  providers: [TodoService],
  animations: [
    trigger('todoAnimations',[
      transition(':enter',[
        group([
          query('h1', [
            useAnimation(moveDown)
          ]),
          query('input', [
            useAnimation(moveDown)
          ]),
          query('@todoItem', [
            stagger(125, animateChild())
          ]),
        ])
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('todoItem', [
      transition(':enter', [
        useAnimation(slideIn)
      ]),
      transition(':leave',[
        useAnimation(slideOut)
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(public service:TodoService) {
    this.refreshList(); 
    console.log(this.service.todoListModel);
    
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.organizeTodosByHour();
  }
    refreshList(){
      this.service.refreshList().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.service.todoListModel=res;
        });
    }
  organizeTodosByHour(){
    do
    {
      if(!this.service.todos) return null;
      this.service.hourlyTodos=groupBy(this.service.todos,[{field: "hour"}]);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.service.hourlyTodos,null,2));
      return 0;
    }
    while(this.service.todoListModel===[])
  }
  public onTimeChange(t:any){
    t.hour=t.due.getHours();
    this.organizeTodosByHour();
    console.log(this.service.todos,this.service.hourlyTodos);
  }
  addTodo(input: HTMLInputElement){
    this.service.todos=[{item:input.value, due: new Date(), hour:(new Date()).getHours()},...this.service.todos];
    input.value='';
    this.organizeTodosByHour();
  }
  removeTodo(i:number){
    this.service.todos.splice(i,1);
    this.organizeTodosByHour();
  }
}
```

please help me by giving me the fix to my problem. It will very helpful if anyone can explain to me how to use await and async.

Comment: You’re using observables. Ansyc/Await is for promises. In order to understand how to work with Observables, you need some understanding of how async works and what to do when.

Comment: I have been working on understanding these things for a while. Can you please help me solve the above code? ```subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.service.todoListModel=res;
        });``` works fine but the 2 lines of code inside the parameter of the subscriber are being executed at the very end impacting the resultset as different methods are unable to fetch data from ```this.service.todos;```

Comment: You need to understand the working of observables for this. Whenever you receive any data on refreshList which is data from API, the block inside subscribe calls itself and gives you the data received from API.

Comment: Why is it a problem that the data for the list is not there right away? It is very common (read as normal) that data, that is loaded via some api from a database is not present when a page with e.g. a list displaying it is loaded. Once the data is acutally there (meaning the subscribe is executed), the view will update and display the loaded data.

Comment: thank you @Gunnar and #Apoorva for your support and for fixing my problem. Please, do upvote my question if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you guys for your efforts, Atlast I did understand `await` and `async` methods and I ended up with the code below:

```
import { animateChild, group, query, stagger, transition, trigger, useAnimation } from '@angular/animations';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { groupBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { moveDown, slideIn, slideOut } from '../animations';
import { TodoService } from '../todo.service';
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css'],
  providers: [TodoService],
  animations: [
    trigger('todoAnimations',[
      transition(':enter',[
        group([
          query('h1', [
            useAnimation(moveDown)
          ]),
          query('input', [
            useAnimation(moveDown)
          ]),
          query('@todoItem', [
            stagger(125, animateChild())
          ]),
        ])
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('todoItem', [
      transition(':enter', [
        useAnimation(slideIn)
      ]),
      transition(':leave',[
        useAnimation(slideOut)
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(public service:TodoService) {
    this.refreshList(); 
    
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  async refreshList(){
    const list$ = this.service.refreshList();
    this.service.todoListModel= await lastValueFrom(list$);
    console.log(this.service.todoListModel);
    this.service.todoListModel.forEach(element => {
      this.service.todos.push({item:element.itemName as string,due:(new Date(element.dueDate)),hour: (new Date(element.dueDate)).getHours()});
    });
    this.organizeTodosByHour();
}

  organizeTodosByHour(){
    if(!this.service.todos) return null;
      this.service.hourlyTodos=groupBy(this.service.todos,[{field: "hour"}]);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.service.hourlyTodos,null,2));
      return 0;
  }

  public onTimeChange(t:any){
    
    t.hour=t.due.getHours();

    this.organizeTodosByHour();
    console.log(this.service.todos,this.service.hourlyTodos);
    
  }

  addTodo(input: HTMLInputElement){
    this.service.todos=[{item:input.value, due: new Date(), hour:(new Date()).getHours()},...this.service.todos];
    input.value='';
    this.organizeTodosByHour();
  }

  removeTodo(i:number){
    this.service.todos.splice(i,1);
    this.organizeTodosByHour();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use async/await, you can use convert observable to promise. There is a method which is being used, but deprecated `toPromise` instead use `lastValueFrom`.

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

constructor(public service:TodoService) {
   (async () => {
         await this.refreshList();
         console.log(this.service.todoListModel);
   })();
  }

async refreshList(){
      const list$ = this.service.refreshList();
      this.service.todoListModel= await lastValueFrom(list$);;
}
```

There are other util observables function too for specific cases, you should check [this](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated) link for more details.

Comment: ```Cannot find name 'lastValueFrom'.``` and ```Cannot find name 'res'.```, these are two errors popping up in your code.

Comment: Ok, I thought you did it. The changes I made worked for you?

Comment: no, On trying to import  ```import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';``` , this error pops up ```Module '"rxjs"' has no exported member 'lastValueFrom'.ts(2305)```

Comment: what RxJs version are you using right now?

Comment: rxjs@6.6.7 version

Comment: It is not available in this version, try updating rxjs to v7+ else use toPromise().

Comment: Yes, I updated it, And still, it has the same problem. ```console.log(this.service.todolistModel)``` giving just an empty array.

Comment: You need to understand how async programming works. When you call `this.refreshList` JS won't wait until you receive data from API instead it will call the next line of the constructor and print the data as of now you data is being fetched from the API in background.  If you want to load the data before loading the component, use resolver from Angular or updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It helped me find the workaround. Instead of calling ```organizeTodosByHour()``` separately in the ```NgOnInit()```. I did called it in refreshList() and thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing that you load the list inside the constructor but you can also load the list in a resolver and data will be present in the component from the start or if you want to do this here just convert Observable to Promise.

```
refreshList(): void {
    this.service.todoListModel =
       await this.service.refreshList().toPromise();
}
```

Comment: firstly, await can be used in an async function. secondly, refreshList() can not be of void type. And finally, correcting these two things we have your code like this:
```async refreshList() {
      this.service.todoListModel =
         await this.service.refreshList().toPromise();
  }```
But it has the same output as my code.

Comment: `toPromise()` is depreciated and shouldn't be used any more instead use `lastValueFrom`